# Sending an email from iPhone through PHP contact page

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've searched but can't find an answer.
There is a website with a contact form, the address end's like this: /?page_id=42, what I want is to send an email from this contact form through the iPhone, without entering the site, through PHP.
From the iPhone textfields.

so I did like this:

```
/?page_id=42contactname=hello&contactsubject=hey&contactemail=yositsa@gmail.com&contactmessage=this is just checking message
```

but I dont know why, it isn't sending me the message, what have I done wrong from the PHP and Objective-C side..
I dont have much knowledge in PHP and I'm new  to Objective-C.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You going to need to include some code for us to see what is wrong ....

Comment: does it work without ios? When you put the url in your desktop browser? Probably not, looks wrong, no escapes and so on. For example page_id is `42contactname`. you forgot a & in between. Make it work from your desktop browser first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like some other people have mentioned - does your PHP contact page use GET request variables? If unsure, check your contact page and look for **$_POST**. If you see this, just as a quick fix change all of your **$_POST** references to **$_REQUESTS** (which allow both POST and GET variables).

If this works, and you'd still like to use POST - then use something like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) in your iOS app to post the variables over.

Comment: I have a 2 files: sendmail.php and contact-form.php.
http://pastebin.com/5kxFHj1v
http://pastebin.com/b761C703

how could I know if to use this page http://www.bergerz.co.il/?page_id=42, or one of the other 2 forms above..?

Comment: In the first pastebin file (pastebin.com/5kxFHj1v) do a FIND & REPLACE for $_POST and replace with $_REQUEST. Then, in your iOS app change the URL to /sendmail.php?$name=MyName&subject=MySubject&email=My@email.com&message=MyMessage

Comment: in this way, it's hackable no? I mean, there is a reason why the man who created this PHP did it with _POST instead of _REQUEST, no?

Comment: Ha, not really - POST isn't really much safer then GET. The only extra security you get by using POST instead of GET is that the POST variables are hidden (until you view source / check your HTTP data). If you want to use POST, you'll need to change your iOS code to POST the data instead of sending the variables via a GET request querystring.

Comment: Dude, that's because you're not passing it a valid email address. Use a proper email address and it'll work (at least it seemed to for me)

Answer (score 2):

URL you mentioned is like

```
`/?page_id=42contactname=hello&contactsubject=hey&contactemail=yositsa@gmail.com&contactmessage=this is just checking message`
```

I suspect here that you are missing & (ampersand) sign between page_id=42 and contactname. I am not sure this is the mistake but currently this is what I see from your current URL.

If this is not the problem try printing variables in which you fetch those parameters as all people have mentioned.

Or post your PHP and iOS side code so we can have a look in to that what is the exact problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The contact form probably works with POST variables. It's not a PHP thing, but an HTML thing.  You need to send the variables in the body of an HTTP request, and you also need that request to be of type POST.

Answer (score 1):

The query string you are trying to use means it's GET request, does your PHP form accept variables from the GET requests ?

Also make sure there are no hidden fields in the form that you might not be including.

Answer (score 1):

I know it may be a bit late, but I just created a drop-in view controller to create an iOS "form" and post the variables to a web server. Not sure if the OP had access to the server side, but you can adapt this code to POST variables to existing web forms too.

It's on Github here:

https://github.com/mikecheckDev/MDContactForm

Let me know if you have any questions about it or need help and/or more features. It is still early in development but I found it useful in my project!